# VF Page in Standard Page Layout - P3P error

Tags: visualforce, security, page-layout

I'm including a VF page into an standard page layout. This error is appearing:

> Your browser privacy settings have prevented this page from showing
>   some Visualforce content.

[image]

After "googled" it, [this](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_browser_security_settings.htm&language=th) is the **Salesforce** recommendation:

> If your browser is set to block third-party cookies, and it does not
>   use the P3P header, and you see an error similar to the one above,
>   perform one of the following actions:
>
> 1. Configure P3P for your browser
> 2. Change your browser settings to allow third-party cookies
> 3. Add the appropriate server to your browser's cookies exception list

The problem is that **I have not control** over final users browser configurations.

Is there any alternative approach like `window.domain = '*.force.com'` ??

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit off the cuff, but try setting the [P3P](http://www.w3.org/P3P/) response header for the Visualforce page to override their default value ("CUR STA OTR").

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('p3p', 'CP="CAO DSP IVAa IVDa OUR BUS UNI OTC"')
```

Note:

1. I'm not certain that this will actually update the response headers or just update the request headers.
2. The values I've added above have worked for me in the past but I can't recall what they are asserting. It would pay to check them.

---

Alternatively, are you explicitly calling `setCookies` on the pageReference in the controller for the Visualforce page? If so, try setting this cookie elsewhere (easier said than done).

Comment: Thx Daniel. I'll try to implement this and tell you how its works